# Count NAs rowwise from multiple variables provided as vector

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, rowwise

I have a data:

```
test_df <- data.frame(x1 = c("a", "b", "c", NA, NA), 
                      x2 = sample(1:5),
                      x3 = c(T, NA, F, T, NA),
                      x4 = c(NA, NA, 1, 2, 3),
                      stringsAsFactors = F)

colset1 <- c("x1", "x2", "x3")
colset2 <- c("x2", "x3", "x4")
```

data frame and vectors containing variable names.

How to check (best in `dplyr` way), if any row of columns provided in a vector (`colset`) contains any `NA`s?

Expected answer for `colset1` is `TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE`, and for `colset2` is `FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE` (best if can be mutated as a new logical variable, doesn't matter).

The alternative question will be: how to count `NA`s in that columns?
Expected answer for `colset1` is `0 1 0 1 2`, and for `colset2` is `1 2 0 0 1`

I was trying with mutating `...ifelse(length(sum(is.na(vars(colset1)))) == 0)` but something was still missing, it didn't work and I got lost in own code :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One `dplyr` solution could be:

```
test_df %>%
 mutate(colset1 = Reduce(`|`, across(colset1, ~ is.na(.))),
        colset2 = Reduce(`|`, across(colset2, ~ is.na(.))))
```

To get the counts:

```
test_df %>%
 mutate(colset1 = rowSums(across(colset1, ~ is.na(.))),
        colset2 = rowSums(across(colset2, ~ is.na(.))))

    x1 x2    x3 x4 colset1 colset2
1    a  3  TRUE NA       0       1
2    b  4    NA NA       1       2
3    c  1 FALSE  1       0       0
4 <NA>  5  TRUE  2       1       0
5 <NA>  2    NA  3       2       1
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for `dplyr`. You can simply use `rowSums`, i.e.

```
!rowSums(is.na(test_df[colset1])) > 0
#[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE

!rowSums(is.na(test_df[colset2])) > 0
#[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

To get the actual number of NAs, you can remove the logical `> 0` and the negate symbol (`!`), i.e.

```
rowSums(is.na(test_df[colset1]))
#[1] 0 1 0 1 2
rowSums(is.na(test_df[colset2]))
#[1] 1 2 0 0 1
```

Answer (score -2):

```
test_df
    x1 x2    x3 x4
1    a  4  TRUE NA
2    b  3    NA NA
3    c  2 FALSE  1
4   NA  5  TRUE  2
5   NA  1    NA  3
is_na(test_df)
        x1    x2    x3    x4
[1,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
[2,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
[3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[4,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[5,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Use na.tools package

Comment: This is not an answer.